# How can I automatically include all firmware needed by selected Linux kernel modules

Tags: compiling, drivers, linux-kernel, kernel-modules, firmware

I have certain modules which I need compiled into the kernel.  Some of these modules require firmware, which used to be automatically included from `/usr/src/linux/firmware/`.  However, no new firmware will be added to this directory, and kernel modules are gradually switching to firmware from `/lib/firmware` instead.  Each time this happens, it appears I need to add the firmware name to `CONFIG_EXTRA_FIRMWARE` in Kconfig.

Is there some way I can automatically collect the list of firmware blobs needed by my compiled-in modules and have them built into the kernel like the `CONFIG_EXTRA_FIRMWARE` option?

To clarify: I could make a list of all drivers I'm building into the kernel, search their source code for references to firmware blobs, and then set `CONFIG_EXTRA_FIRMWARE` to this list of files. But this process would be time consuming and error prone. I want it to happen automatically and reliably.

Comment: What kernel is it?

Comment: I just switched from Linux 3.2 to 3.10, so I'm looking for a solution for 3.10 and forward.

Comment: also, I clarified the context of why I need this.